# org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to push some records into Elastic search using an `API` based on `Bulk` request. Out of 7000 records,only around 1000+ is getting into `elastic` search without any problem. But the number varies time to time. `Elastic` search is not making any rejection. The `API` I have used and exception I got while executing the same is given.

```
public int getData(String currentDate,String count)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, ParseException {
    int x=Integer.parseInt(count);
    String url= *Some URL*
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    JsonFactory f = new MappingJsonFactory();
    JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(rd);
    JsonToken current = null;
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        try {
            current = jp.nextToken();
            JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
            if (node != null) {
                x=x+1;
                sendDataToES(node,x);
            } else {

                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("ES data push failed");
        }
    }
    return x;
}


public void sendDataToES(JsonNode node,int count) throws IOException,
ParseException {

    String lat = null,lon = null;
    TransportClient client = getClient().addTransportAddress(
            new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
    XContentBuilder jsonObject = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
            .startObject();
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> entry = node.fields();
    Entry<String, JsonNode> a = null;
    while (entry.hasNext()) {
        try {
            a = entry.next();
            if (a.getKey().equals("longitude")) {
                  lon=a.getValue().asText();

            }
            if(a.getKey().equals("latitude")){
                  lat=a.getValue().asText();
            }
            jsonObject.field(a.getKey()).value(a.getValue().asText());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("lat", lat);
    map.put("lon", lon);
    jsonObject.field("location")
        .value(map)

    .endObject();

    try
    {
    bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("bulk_data", "data",
            String.valueOf((count))).setSource(jsonObject));
    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
    logger.info("Data has been posted to elastic search");
    if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
        logger.info("Got failure while pushing data to ES");
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.info("Got failure while pushing data to ES");
    }
    client.close();
}
```

I'm getting the following `Exception`,

```
org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector.
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(AbstractNioSelector.java:362)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.<init>(AbstractNioSelector.java:100)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.<init>(AbstractNioWorker.java:52)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.<init>(NioWorker.java:45)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.newWorker(NioWorkerPool.java:44)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.newWorker(NioWorkerPool.java:28)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorkerPool.init(AbstractNioWorkerPool.java:80)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.<init>(NioWorkerPool.java:39)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.<init>(NioWorkerPool.java:33)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.createClientBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:319)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:242)
at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:153)
at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:197)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:133)
```

Comment: Please mention Elasticsearch version.

Comment: Elastic search version :- 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue with the code

```
public void sendStatusHistoryToES(JsonNode node,int count) throws IOException,
ParseException {

    String lat = null,lon = null;
    TransportClient client = getClient().addTransportAddress(
            new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
```

For each bulk request  , another client is created and a new port is opened.
And eventually its giving no more port exception.

Place the client initialization in constructor or something and things should be fine.

Put the below in constructor -

```
    TransportClient client = getClient().addTransportAddress(
            new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
```